# How can I remove all deleted messages from mail trash folder on default email app

Tags: email

This question has already been asked here but no satisfactory answers were given. Some say to go to trash folder and select mails one by one then delete; I will NOT select 250 mails one by one!! Others say to go to the mail providers web site... if I wanted to do that then I would not ask this question. Anyway, even if I do that (I'm not talking about g-mail, but other providers I have accounts with) the mails will remain physically on the android phone in the trash folder...

The problem is that in the default Android mail app, there is no Select All option for messages, and there is no Delete from trash option. There must be some way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: As there is nothing like *the* default mail app (every manufacturer is free to install its own, and most do): Specifying your device and Android version would help finding answers. // Besides: what protocol are you using? With IMAP, when deleting mails on the server, they should automatically be deleted on the client as well. Are you by chance using POP3?

Comment: I have found a Android issue where this problem is being adresses.
Hopefully when we all want this issue being solved it will be solved. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10232

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the system-e-mails apps (e-mail and gmail) on my Nexus4 is able to accomplish that task - very annoying indeed.

So the basic answer is propably: You can not.

But there are mail-apps capable of doing so. One of it is [K9-mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9).